# how to read function outside useEffect in react | not working onclick button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote the Code and it has a separate script file, but when I click on the button next or before, the nextPrev does not work , I have put all the JS codes into the useEffect and I don't know if this method is correct or not

i can't read function inside in `useEffect` and show me this error:
‍‍‍‍‍‍`Line 174:57:  'nextPrev' is not defined  no-undef`

```
const AddTest = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
      var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
      showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
      
      function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
      }
      
      function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
          // ... the form gets submitted:
          document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
          return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
      }
      
      function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          // If a field is empty...
          if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false
            valid = false;
          }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
      }
      
      function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
      }
  },[])
    return (
        <>
        <div className="row">
          <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
        <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span className="stepIndicator">تنظیمات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">سوالات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">تفسیر</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">پیش نمایش</span>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">درصد افیلیت</label>
                <p className="text-muted">درصدی از هزینه تست که میخواهید به پزشک یا نمایندگان اختصاص داده شود را تعیین کنید.</p>
                <div className="form-row">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">5 درصد</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">10 درصد</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Your presence on the social network</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Linked In" oninput="this.className = ''" name="linkedin" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter" oninput="this.className = ''" name="twitter" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook" oninput="this.className = ''" name="facebook" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" oninput="this.className = ''" name="mobile" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onClick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onClick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>

        </div>
      </> 
    );
  };
  
  export default AddTest;
```

Comment: I think you just need to move nextPrev outside the useEffect function and it should work. I dont think the return function has access to nextPrev because the function is declared inside useEffect.

Comment: i can't do that , you can do this way? @DustinSpengler

Comment: You can't call it because it is defined in a different scope. Move that function out side of useEffect function. You don't need it to be defined in useEffect.

Comment: Note that you should avoid manipulating the DOM directly, it's ineficient and may lead to subtle bugs in your code, + the whole purpose of an UI library is to avoid having to deal with the DOM imperatively

Comment: @Meerkat it's not working , i edited my code

Comment: @Calfut it's look good and working but not working only `onclick`

Comment: onClick={() => nextPrev(1)} Use this instead in the button element. This will work.

Comment: @Meerkat same error :/

Comment: Did you move nextPrev function outside of useEffect and replaced onClick event handler? It should have worked if you did that.

Comment: @Meerkat when i moved nextPrev Outside of useeffect show this `error`: ` Line 88:7:    'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 90:5:    'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 90:18:   'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 92:9:    'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 98:5:    'showTab' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 98:13:   'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 193:57:  'nextPrev' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 194:57:  'nextPrev' is not defined `

Comment: Check my answer below. But I recommend you to go through the react documentation once, before you get down to develop React app. There're differences between normal javascript and React application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respectfully, your code is quite confusing to read. If you are using React, then use React! Someone else provided you with a Code Sandbox, but here is yet [another](https://codesandbox.io/s/function-outside-useeffect-qsjtr7?file=/src/components/AddTest.jsx).

Pay attention at how, with React, you have *no need* to use `document.getElementById`, etc. If you need a reference to a DOMElement, then use `useRef` (e.g. `<div ref={ ref } ... />`, accessible via `ref.current`).

```
import { useState } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";

const DEFAULT_FORM_DATA = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  companyName: "",
  notes: "",
  radioValue: 0, // ????
  email: "",
  password: "",
  passwordConfirm: "",
  fullname: "",
  address: "",
  mobile: "",
  linkedin: "",
  twitter: "",
  facebook: ""
};

const AddTest = () => {
  // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(DEFAULT_FORM_DATA);
  const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const key = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const valid = value !== "";

    setFormValid((formValid) => ({ ...formValid, [key]: valid }));
    setFormData((formData) => ({ ...formData, [key]: value }));
  };

  const handlePreviousTab = () =>
    setCurrentTab((currentTab) => Math.max(currentTab - 1, 0));
  const handleNextTab = () =>
    setCurrentTab((currentTab) => Math.min(currentTab + 1, 3));
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("TODO : submit formData = ", formData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
          <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span
              className={classnames("stepIndicator", {
                active: currentTab === 0
              })}
            >
              تنظیمات
            </span>
            <span
              className={classnames("stepIndicator", {
                active: currentTab === 1
              })}
            >
              سوالات
            </span>
            <span
              className={classnames("stepIndicator", {
                active: currentTab === 2
              })}
            >
              تفسیر
            </span>
            <span
              className={classnames("stepIndicator", {
                active: currentTab === 3
              })}
            >
              پیش نمایش
            </span>
          </div>

          <div
            className="step"
            style={{ display: currentTab === 0 ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className={classnames("form-control", {
                    invalid: formValid.firstName === false
                  })}
                  name="firstName"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  required
                  value={formData.firstName}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className={classnames("form-control", {
                    invalid: formValid.lastName === false
                  })}
                  name="lastName"
                  placeholder="Last name"
                  required
                  value={formData.lastName}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  name="notes"
                  value={formData.notes}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className={classnames("form-control", {
                    invalid: formValid.firstName === false
                  })}
                  id="companyName"
                  name="companyName"
                  placeholder="Company name"
                  required
                  value={formData.companyName}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label
                htmlFor="companyName"
                className="font-weight-bold text-right"
              >
                درصد افیلیت
              </label>
              <p className="text-muted">
                درصدی از هزینه تست که میخواهید به پزشک یا نمایندگان اختصاص داده
                شود را تعیین کنید.
              </p>
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="radioValue5"
                    name="radioValue"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    value={5}
                    checked={formData.radioValue === "5"}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                  <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="radioValue5">
                    5 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="radioValue10"
                    name="radioValue"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    value={10}
                    checked={formData.radioValue === "10"}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    htmlFor="radioValue10"
                  >
                    10 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            className="step"
            style={{ display: currentTab === 1 ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="email"
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="password"
                value={formData.password}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="passwordConfirm"
                value={formData.passwordConfirm}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            className="step"
            style={{ display: currentTab === 2 ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            <p className="text-center mb-4">
              Your presence on the social network
            </p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Linked In"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="linkedin"
                value={formData.linkedin}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Twitter"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="twitter"
                value={formData.twitter}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Facebook"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="facebook"
                value={formData.facebook}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            className="step"
            style={{ display: currentTab === 3 ? "" : "none" }}
          >
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Full name"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="fullname"
                value={formData.fullname}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Mobile"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="mobile"
                value={formData.mobile}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Address"
                onInput={(e) => (e.target.className = "")}
                name="address"
                value={formData.address}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button
              type="button"
              id="prevBtn"
              onClick={handlePreviousTab}
              style={{ display: currentTab > 0 ? "" : "none" }}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              id="nextBtn"
              onClick={currentTab === 3 ? handleSubmit : handleNextTab}
            >
              {currentTab === 3 ? "Submit" : "Next"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTest;
```

Consider watching or reading some tutorials on using React, and then try to adopt best practices when using the framework. This will not only make your code easier to read for others, it will help you actually use the framework how it is intended.

#### Note

The "next" button may become a submit button if you want to submit the form through the browser instead of manually handling it. If this is the intention, you could change the button with

```
<button
  type={ currentTab === 3 ? "submit", : "button" }
  id="nextBtn"
  onClick={currentTab === 3 ? null : handleNextTab}
>
  {currentTab === 3 ? "Submit" : "Next"}
</button>
```

Comment: it's not currect way o use button `{currentTab === 3 ? "Submit" : "Next"}` , i want to send post api in last step , by the way your code working tabs but don't show tabs body (inputs va ...)

Comment: Without an actual working example, it is difficult to reproduce the visual of your project. The idea is to show you how you can refactor your code in order to properly use React, and why you might not need `useEffect` at all. In any case, you definitely should not use `document.getElementById` or other element selector... unless you really need it.

Comment: i your code answer how i can manage submit button?

in last step when user click on submit ,  how i can send post api?

Comment: @Sarah I have updated my Code Sandbox and my answer. You just need to provide a different handler function to the button

Comment: @Sarah YouTube has great resources, constantly updated tutorials. Just type "learn react {year}" (where {year} is the current year, ex: "learn react 2022") and look for less than 12 months old videos. And, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: thanks mr
I have seen YouTube videos even udemy videos,  But it was not very effective I generally know what to do, but I am weak in solving partial problems and algorithms

Comment: Excellence comes with experience; build apps along with those who provide tutorials, and learn to adopt [design patterns](https://blog.devgenius.io/design-patterns-in-programming-how-and-when-to-use-them-feaf6ce4aefd) while avoiding the [anti-patterns](https://mennan-sevim.medium.com/what-is-anti-pattern-d226fa75112b). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const AddTest = () => {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = React.useState(0);

  function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i,
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
  }

  function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == x.length - 1) {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n);
  }

  function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    setCurrentTab((curTab) => curTab + n);
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
      // ... the form gets submitted:
      document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
      return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
  }

  function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x,
      y,
      i,
      valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      // If a field is empty...
      if (y[i].value == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        y[i].className += " invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false
        valid = false;
      }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className +=
        " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
          <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span className="stepIndicator">تنظیمات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">سوالات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">تفسیر</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">پیش نمایش</span>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom01"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom02"
                  placeholder="Last name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom01"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label for="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">
                درصد افیلیت
              </label>
              <p className="text-muted">
                درصدی از هزینه تست که میخواهید به پزشک یا نمایندگان اختصاص داده
                شود را تعیین کنید.
              </p>
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadioInline1"
                    name="customRadioInline1"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    for="customRadioInline1"
                  >
                    5 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadioInline2"
                    name="customRadioInline1"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    for="customRadioInline2"
                  >
                    10 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="email"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="password"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">
              Your presence on the social network
            </p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Linked In"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="linkedin"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Twitter"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="twitter"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Facebook"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="facebook"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Full name"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="fullname"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Mobile"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="mobile"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Address"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="address"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onClick={() => nextPrev(-1)}>
              Previous
            </button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onClick={() => nextPrev(1)}>
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I set `currentTab` as a state so I think you don't need to worry about useEffect:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const AddTest = () => {
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);

  function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == x.length - 1) {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n);
  }

  function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    setCurrentTab(currentTab + n);
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
      // ... the form gets submitted:
      document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
      return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
  }

  function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x,
      y,
      i,
      valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      // If a field is empty...
      if (y[i].value == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        y[i].className += " invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false
        valid = false;
      }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className +=
        " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
  }

  function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i,
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
          <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span className="stepIndicator">تنظیمات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">سوالات</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">تفسیر</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">پیش نمایش</span>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom01"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom02"
                  placeholder="Last name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="validationCustom01"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label for="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">
                درصد افیلیت
              </label>
              <p className="text-muted">
                درصدی از هزینه تست که میخواهید به پزشک یا نمایندگان اختصاص داده
                شود را تعیین کنید.
              </p>
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadioInline1"
                    name="customRadioInline1"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    for="customRadioInline1"
                  >
                    5 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadioInline2"
                    name="customRadioInline1"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    for="customRadioInline2"
                  >
                    10 درصد
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="email"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="password"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">
              Your presence on the social network
            </p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Linked In"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="linkedin"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Twitter"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="twitter"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Facebook"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="facebook"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Full name"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="fullname"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Mobile"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="mobile"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Address"
                oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="address"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick={() => nextPrev(-1)}>
              Previous
            </button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick={() => nextPrev(1)}>
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTest;
```

Comment: @it's working but when i click on next , not show another step

Comment: what the output should be when clicked next ? can you explain more specific?

Comment: When I click next it should show next step: `<div className="step">`  | When I click on Next, it does not go to the next step

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73735645/19985907 he had implemented it.

Comment: please edit your code , I can't handle this code with this guy way

Answer (score 0):

I created this CodeSandBox to guide you in the react way. I only added handling the next and prev steps. https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-feather-cr801y?file=/src/App.js

It's better to read about form handling:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_forms.asp
https://ibaslogic.com/simple-guide-to-react-form/

Or you can use a package like [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) to help.

Comment: but it is not my code

Comment: @Sarah you should understand that code and implement it that way. The code which you had done is not React based and it will not work properly.

Comment: PLEASE EDIT MY CODE , I can't handle this code with your way

Comment: @Sarah other people should not do your job. Learn from the provided example and refactor your own code, please.

Comment: @Sarah what an irony!! The code you provided is definitely not working, but my Code Sandbox is. Your question asks how to use `useEffect` but you don't need `useEffect`. I'm not the only one telling you the same thing : learn how to use React!

Comment: thanks, What resources do you recommend for learning this content in depth? @YanickRochon

Comment: @Sarah You can see how react hooks work here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html This is where I learned it. And for form handing, you can refer to the links in the answer.